# Analytic function in $\mathbb{C}\backslash \{0\}$ that is identically zero

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose $f$ is an analytic function in $\mathbb{C}\backslash \{0\}$ and satisfies the inequality $|f(z)| \leq c|z||Logz|$ ($z \in \mathbb{C}\backslash \{0\}$), for some constant $c >0$. Prove that $f(z)=0$ for every $z \in \mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$.

My try:

Note that $f(1)=0$. So its suffice to show that $|f'(z)|=0$. Let $\gamma$ be circular path with center in $z \in \mathbb{C}\backslash \{0\} $ and appropriate radius $r>0$. Using the Cauchy Theorem for derivates we have
\begin{align}
|f'(z)|&=\left| \int_{\gamma}\dfrac{f(\xi)}{(\xi - z)^2}d\xi \right| \\
&\leq \int_{\gamma}\dfrac{|f(\xi)|}{|\xi - z|^2}|d\xi| \\
&\leq c \int_{\gamma}\dfrac{|\xi||Log\xi|}{r^2}|d\xi| 
\end{align}

But now I can't conclude what I want. Is not the correct aproach?

Comment: Since $\xi\in\gamma$ you have $|\xi|=r$, and use $\log \xi = \ln r + i\theta$. The integral now becomes $$\int_\gamma \frac{\ln r + i\theta}{r}|d\xi| = 2\pi\ln r .$$ Doesn't seem to work out.

Comment: What do you mean by $\log z$ on $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}?$

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Certainly a logarithm can be defined on that set, just not continuously. That is maybe what is meant.

Comment: @zhw. Sure. ${}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Although your approach seems to fail, you can actually use Cauchy's integral formula for higher orders to make the log radius term insignificant. For instance, use $n=2$ we have
$$|f''(z)|\le C\int_\gamma \frac{r(|\ln r| + |i\theta|)}{r^3}|d\xi|\le 2\pi r \frac{r(|\ln r| + 2\pi)}{r^3}\le C'\frac{\ln r}{r}$$
where $C,C'$ denote appropriate constants. Now let $r\to\infty$.

Caveat: there might be a little problem with the complex $\log$ since it has a "jump" along its "faultline". However, since we only use $\log z$ for our estimating the magnitude of $|f|$, this problem doesn't affect our proof here because one jump contributes at most a $i2\pi=O(1)$ which is thus negligible.

<strike>Note: $f$ isn't holomorphic on the closed disk $|z|\le r$, and Cauchy is inapplicable here.</strike>

Note 2: per the discussion in the below comments, $0$ is a removable singularity, so the approach still works.

Note 3: my approach actually proves $f$ is either zero or linear, but doesn't exclude the possibility that $f$ is linear (which if we don't specify the choice of the log branch will always persist, see the comment by another user below). However, if you specify that $\log 1=0$, then $f$ must be zero. This isn't implied by my "proof" here, but follows from the user's argument in the comments below (Liouville's theorem and something).

Comment: The solution  is that $f$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$. So $f$ is entire and bounded by $C(1+|z^{1+\epsilon}|)$ so by Liouville's theorem (or the Cauchy's integral formula as you did) it is a polynomial of degree $1$. But  $f$ has a zero at $z=0$ so $f(z) =  a z$ and hence it doesn't have a zero at $z=1$, a contradiction with $|f(z)| \le c |z \log z|$. Choosing another branch of $\log$ having no zero, we obtain $f(z) = a z$ as a solution

Comment: @user1952009 no $f$ isn't defined at $0$. No guarantee it is entire. (And this makes the Cauchy integral formula inapplicable... yeah my approach is wrong.)

Comment: @user1952009 ok. I'm sorry I'm kinda rusty on complex analysis now. There's a singularity classification theorem and $0$ isn't a pole nor an essential singularity. (Your comment just rang the bell for me). But I'm not sure the OP has learned the classification theorem yet.

Comment: $f$ is analytic on $|z| > 0$ and bounded as $z \to 0$, so $z=0$ is a [removable singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity)  (think to $g(z) = f(z) z^2$ which is holomorphic at $z=0$)

Comment: You need to show that $f$ is analytic at $z=0$ before using the Cauchy integral theorem with $\gamma = \{ |z| = r\}$. Then you obtain $f'' = 0$ which is the same as $f$ being a polynomial of degree $1$.

Comment: @user1952009 Nevermind. I got it. My approach actually can't exclude the possibility $f=az$. For the removability, as you said, $f$ is bounded near zero.

Comment: Yes $f(z) = az$ is solution, and $\log(1) = 0 \implies a=0$